# How nginx process =404 fallback in try_files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a example web server with only one index.html file in a www directory. I can setup a nginx with following configuration:

```
location /subfolder {
     alias /data/www;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

In browser I can see correct response on my local domain `test.local/subfolder`, also `test.local/subfolder/something` returns a default nginx page (it is normal because root is not set)

if I change a configuration to

```
location /subfolder {
     alias /data/www;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

response to `test.local/subfolder` is still correct, but `test.local/subfolder/something` and all URI with /subfolder prefix return a index.html of correct response also status is 200 not 404. If I remove `/index` from try_files I get the same result

I wonder how nginx process request with =404 fallback, but cant find any information, not even in a official docs.

UDAPTE:

I found out that a alias directive should end with an `/` but still dont get a =404 functionality and purpose because a status is still 200ok

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`try_files`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive only supports these syntaxes:

```
try_files file ... uri;
try_files file ... =code;
```

It doesn't support:

```
try_files file ... uri =code;
```

The difference between `file` and `uri` here, is that for `file` arguments, NGINX will check their *existence* before moving on to next argument; for `uri`, it won't.

If the last argument has form of a `=code`, then all prior arguments to it are `file`s (checked for existence).

From this, you can get a conclusion that with request URI `/foo/bar` and this config:

```
root /var/www;
location /foo/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

... Will not trigger 404 error if any of the `file`s exist:

- `/var/www/foo/bar`
- `/var/www/foo/bar/` directory (if you have `autoindex` enabled)
- `/var/www/foo/bar/index.html` (or `index.php`, etc.) (due to value of `index`)

*Only* when none of the above exist, NGINX will trigger 404 error.

Comment: I checked a supported syntax and It is as you said, so can I rewrite my configuration in this way `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html =404`?

Answer (score 12):

You should define the root of your server, then the default indexes and then add the `=404` to `try_files`:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/html/example.com;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;
  # This is optional - if you want a customized 404 error page
  error_page 404 /404.html;

  location /subfolder {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

The difference between `root` and `alias` is that `root` appends `location` to get the absolute path in the filesystem while `alias` excludes the `location`. So for example when you try to fetch `http://example.com/subfolder/filename.txt`

```
server_name example.com;
root /var/www/html/example;

location /subfolder {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

will return the contents of `/var/www/html/example/subfolder/filename.txt` (if it exists) while

```
server_name example.com;

location /subfolder {
  alias /var/log;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

will return the contents of `/var/log/filename.txt` (if it exists)