# NGINX and Gatsby: Setting up nginx to route to Gatsby 404 page

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, config

I have a Gatsby site set up with nginx. I know that Gatsby uses whatever component that exists in the `pages/404.js` as the 404 page. If I navigate to [www.mysite.com/404](http://www.mysite.com/404) I can see the custom Gatsby 404 page I created, however this is the only time I see the Gatsby 404 component. If I navigate to [www.mysite.com/blahblahblah](http://www.mysite.com/blahblahblah) or any other non-existent page I see the default white nginx 404 page.

I'm familiar with Gatsby but a noob when it comes to nginx. How can I set up my nginx config to redirect my users to my custom Gatsby 404 component when the user navigates to a non-existent page instead of showing the default nginx 404 page?

Here is my nginx config:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    sendfile on;
    
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just in the same situation. I'll share what (seems to have) worked for me. Like you, I'm using Gatsby and I have a file at `pages/404.js` that I'd like to use as a catch-all for missing routes. I found the answer given by @ivo-gelov here helpful: [How nginx process =404 fallback in try_files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561236/how-nginx-process-404-fallback-in-try-files?rq=1)

Specifically, I just added an error_page definition to match up with the `=404` error code:

```
  error_page 404 /404.html;
```

```
  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
```

Comment: but these two directives lead to soft 404, not good for SEO.